# Stream file through 2 rest calls spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, download

I am trying to download zip file from service A, where it calls service B for file. I need a solution to stream file across services
example when i call service A for file, it will call Service B. from here it should stream to Service A. from service A it'll stream to the caller.

The reason for stream between services is, i don't want to store the file in service A. i just want to pass to the caller without storing it.

And also let me know which option to use in service A. like ByteArrayResource or rest template response extractor etc..

Limitation Service B is not in my control so as of now i am accepting file as byte array
Here is the small simulation in single controller

`@RestController
public class FileUploadController {
  
  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  
  // Assume this is from Service A
  @PostMapping(value = "/downloadresource",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> downloadByteResource() throws IOException{
    ByteArrayResource responseObject;
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new LinkedMultiValueMap<>());
    responseObject= restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/test", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,
        ByteArrayResource.class).getBody();
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=test.zip")
        .body(responseObject);
  }
  // Assume below from service B. which is not in my control
  @PostMapping(value="/test")
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> test() throws IOException {
    File f = new File("/Users/dummy/Downloads/test.zip");
    byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=" + f.getName())
        .body(b);
  }

}`

Comment: what did you try for now ?

Comment: currently i am using byte[] even in service A. because of it i will run out of memory on more requests at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got some solution which is working with low memory as per visulaVM(to visualise heap memory).

Please let me know if any other better options.

`@PostMapping(value = "/downloadextract",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> downloadExtract(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new LinkedMultiValueMap<>());
    ResponseExtractor<Object> extractor  = restClient -> {
      StreamUtils.copy(restClient.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
      return null;
    };
    RequestCallback callback = req -> {
      req.getHeaders().add("auth", "token");
    };
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
        "attachment; filename=test.zip");
    restTemplate.execute("http://localhost:8081/test", HttpMethod.POST, callback,
        extractor);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }`